# Propper way to describe request body as java class

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is the propper way to describe json body like this in spring-boot app?

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "releaseDate": "2000-01-01",
  "description": "desc",
  "duration": 10,
  "rate": 1,
  "mpa": { "id": 3},
  "genres": [{ "id": 1}]
}
```

For now i have class like bellow, but i have problem with serialization of `mpa` and `genres` fields.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Film extends Entity implements Comparable<Film> {

    @Builder
    public Film(long id, String name, @NonNull String description, @NonNull LocalDate releaseDate, @NonNull int duration, List<Genre> genres, Rating mpa, Set<Long> likes) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.genres = genres;
        this.mpa = mpa;
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    @NotBlank
    private final String name;
    @NonNull
    @Size(max = 200, message = "Description name longer than 200 symbols")
    private final String description;
    @NonNull
    @Past
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @NonNull
    @Positive
    private int duration;

    private Rating mpa;

    private List<Genre> genres;

    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private Set<Long> likes;
}
```

`Genre` and `Rating`:

```
@Data
public class Genre {

    @Positive
    private final long id;

}
```

```
@Data
public class Rating {

    @Positive
    private final long id;

}
```

Comment: This looks ok on first sight, what problems do you have during serialization?

Comment: Looks proper to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson `ObjectMapper` cannot create the object, because neither default constructor exists nor any other creator is provided (e.g. `@JsonCreator`, `@ConstructorProperties`).

You also have a `rate` property that is not defined in the `Film` class, which will cause problems unless you use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation (possibly with `ignoreUnknown` attribute set to `true`) or configure the ObjectMapper globally (`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`). It could also be that you wanted the `likes` property to handle that - anyway, it should be fixed.

I've also stumbled upon lack of the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency, but maybe your project already has it (it's required for the Java 8 classes like `LocalDate`).

---

There are different ways to solve the first problem described above, but generally you need to either provide a default constructor or define a creator for Jackson.

If you don't want to expose the default constructor, you can change the settings of the ObjectMapper (for Spring Boot read about `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`) to allow usage of private creators (`setVisibility` method). In Lombok there's an annotation: `@NoArgsConstructor`. To limit the visibility, use the `access` annotation attribute.

The creator can be handled by annotating the constructor with ordered argument names:
`@ConstructorProperties({"id", "name", "description", "releaseDate", "duration", "genres", "mpa", "likes"})`. It gets complicated with the `Genre` and `Rating` classes as you do not have an explicit access to their constructors. You could either create them and mark appropriately or create a **lombok.config** file in your project's root directory and inside the file define the property:

`lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true`

This way Lombok will automatically add the `@ConstructorProperties` annotations to the classes.

---

I've created a GitHub repository with the tests for the solution - you can find it [here](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/73296988). The [lombok.config file](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73296988/lombok.config) is also included, as well as [the fixed Film class](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73296988/src/main/java/io/github/jonarzz/solution/FixedFilm.java).

Comment: Gonna say you're the first one saving answers` code on GitHub, that's brilliant! I'll start doing it myself, too!

Comment: So i defined Genre and Rating as nested static classes. Both of them and Film class i had annotated with @ConstructorProperties and it worked out! 
Also i had tried to use addConstructorProperties as u said to simplify code, but it seems that lombok ignores lomboc.config file at all.
Thanks u a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In another way, I put **Genre** and **Rating** classes in **Film** class and the variables are not **final** in **Genre** and **Rating** ,  tried like this and it worked

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Film extends Entity implements Comparable<Film> {

@Builder
public Film(long id, String name, @NonNull String description, @NonNull LocalDate releaseDate, @NonNull int duration, List<Genre> genres, Rating mpa, Set<Long> likes) {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.genres = genres;
    this.mpa = mpa;
    this.likes = likes;
}

@NotBlank
private final String name;
@NonNull
@Size(max = 200, message = "Description name longer than 200 symbols")
private final String description;
@NonNull
@Past
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private LocalDate releaseDate;

@NonNull
@Positive
private int duration;

private Rating mpa;

private List<Genre> genres;

@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
private Set<Long> likes;

@Data
public static class Genre {

  @Positive
  private long id;

}

@Data
public static class Rating {

  @Positive
  private long id;

}
}
```